# CircleCI is stuck at `mix test`

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, circleci

I have a simple CircleCI config file for an Elixir umbrella project. When run, it gets stuck at the last step `mix test` and eventually times out. I have tried different things but none has worked.

What did I miss or do wrong in the config file?

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    services:
      - rabbitmq-server
      - redis
    docker:
      - image: circleci/elixir:1.5.2    
    working_directory: ~/my-project
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install hex, rebar
          command: |
            mix local.hex --force
            mix local.rebar --force
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: mix deps.get
      - run:
          name: Test warning-free compilation
          command: mix compile --warnings-as-errors
      - run:
          name: Run unit tests
          command: mix test
```

Comment: How long does `mix test` take when you run it locally? Do your tests talk to Redis and RabbitMQ? If yes, can you debug whether your tests can connect to these services?

Comment: If I run `mix test` from terminal on my machine, it takes about 10 seconds. Yes, the tests talk to Redis and RabbitMQ. However, the problem is CircleCI remains stuck at the very first test which is a mere `doctest` in Elixir. It even does not get a chance to execute the tests that talk to Redis and RabbitMQ. Please let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that it's stuck in the `doctest`? Have you tried removing all tests but the single one? (A quick internet search turned up https://elixirforum.com/t/running-all-tests-in-test-folder/4121/3, where the author mentions that `mix test` randomizes the ordering of tests)

Comment: When `mix test` starts unit tests, it first outputs the app name to console, then runs the unit tests and shows test results. In this case, I see name of first app on console, then nothing. This happens even when the first app only has a `doctest`.

Comment: You can confirm which test it gets stuck on by running `mix test --trace` which prints the name of the test before executing it.

Comment: Things got more interesting after adding `--trace`. When I run `mix test --trace` from terminal, it prints first app name, then test module name, then each individual test name. When run by CircleCI, it gets stuck after printing app name. It doesn't even print the test module name! Does that give any clue?